# Adding domain to UrlValidator in apache.commons

Tags: java, url, apache-commons, url-validation

So I am using the Commons UrlValidator (org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator) and I was wondering if there was a way to customize the domains it allows. Right now it seems to only allow TLD's but I have one or two I want to be valid that arent on that list e.g ".corp" (list is found here: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt). Is there a setting or a work around so I dont have to create my own url validator and can just use this one with the added domains?

Answer (score 5):

You can find below a JUnit test case.

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator;
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

class UrlValidatorTestCase extends TestCase {

  private static final String[] GENERIC_TLDS_PLUS = new String[] { "corp" };

  static {
    DomainValidator.updateTLDOverride(DomainValidator.ArrayType.GENERIC_PLUS, GENERIC_TLDS_PLUS);
  }

  public void test_UrlValidator_isValid_corp_tld() {
    assertTrue(UrlValidator.getInstance().isValid("http://domainlabel.corp"));
  }
}
```

Tested with commons-validator 1.6

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a possible way to do it, but i did not use it or implement it. When the url is not valid I was going to put it into another check using the DomainValidator ([source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.html)). I was planning on using the updateTLDOverride method, but they have a bug in v 1.5.0 where a parameter of the method call uses a private or protected variable. This was fixed in 1.5.1 but I was using Maven and the repo only goes to version 1.5.0 for the validators.